# Why is specific volume of saturated water greater at 1 MPA than at 0.1 MPA during the phase change process?

Tags: thermodynamics, water, phase-transition

Why is specific volume of saturated water greater at 1 MPA than at 0.1 MPA during the phase change process?

check out the T-V diagram here in the link.
http://www.ohio.edu/mechanical/thermo/Intro/Chapt.1_6/Chapter2a.html

Comment: *Saturated water*? Can you explain what this means and ideally give a link to an article that describes the specific volumes you mention?

Comment: By Saturated water I mean water that is about to vaporize.

Comment: Do you mean, why the specific volume is bigger at higher pressure before it starts vaporizing? Are you at the Saturated Liquid line?

Comment: Yes Steeven exactly.

Comment: Yeah I'm at the line connecting the saturated liquid to the saturated vapour,i wanted to know why the line gets shorter as the pressure increases

Comment: I edited the title. Please have a look at [our FAQ on writing good titles](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6413/how-do-we-write-good-question-titles).

Comment: You are comparing saturated water at two very different temperatures, as well as two very different pressures.

Answer (score 1):

For saturated water, you must have vapor and liquid water together, presumably at thermal equilibrium.  In addition, the pressure of the saturated water must be the vapor pressure at the specified temperature. The Antoine equation specifies vapor pressure as a function of temperature, and it also says that a higher vapor pressure corresponds to a higher temperature.  At higher temperatures (hence, at higher pressures), the density of liquid water is lower, so the specific volume is higher.

For further info, see 
http://antoine.frostburg.edu/chem/senese/101/liquids/faq/antoine-vapor-pressure.shtml